# how to sanitize checkbox input?

Tags: metabox, sanitization

I've added meta box: checkbox on admin edit screen

```
<input type="checkbox" name="changeposition" />
```

So how could we sanitize the input came from the checkbox as we do for input type text by `sanitize_text_field()`. Is there any function like this for checkbox sanitization or should we create custom method for it?

Comment: You can use [`absint()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/absint/).

Comment: I do not think you will need it. Text field value come from user input here in checkbox you are setting the value. However, value can be modified by HTML inspector, so you can use the same function `sanitize_text_field()`.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to set the value in your markup. You should have.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="changeposition" value="yes" />
```

Then, I'd suggest using [`sanitize_key()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_key/) to sanitize.

> Keys are used as internal identifiers. Lowercase alphanumeric
>   characters, dashes and underscores are allowed.

*Think of the word `yes`, as a key. That's what you're expecting is a lowercase alphanumeric value.*

---

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

> If the value attribute was omitted, the submitted data would be given a default value of on, so the submitted data in that case would be subscribe=on.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function in PHP. 
It has some predefined filters thats you can use.

To sanitize a number:

```
$sanitizedCheckbox = filter_var( $yourVar, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
```

For a string you would just change `_NUM_INT` to `_STRING`.